# Correct form of writing hints for math charts

Tags: articles, mathematics

I have a math chart (there are multiple curves btw) and want to write some hints below.

Here's a sentence that describes what it means when one (or many) of the curves is/are green:

**"green - parameter is within optimal range for the current condition."**

Should I put any article before the "parameter" word? Is the sentence correct if I omit any article at all?

Comment: Yes, omission of words like articles is common in places where space is at a premium -- headlines, instruction manuals, signs, labels, and (your example) explanatory asides.

Comment: Hmm. If there is only one parameter, what you have as a legend is fine. If there are multiple parameters, you need to specify which is being discussed. Because your wording indicates that either singular or plural applies in at least some cases, I am a bit uncertain about whether "parameter" or "parameters" applies. I provide help at a math site, and if a student can view a problem as at all ambiguous, at least some will.